# Anyone else seeing ellipsis in Apple's Developer Library website?

Tags: ios, firefox

I don't know if it's the new iOS SDK 5 documentation or an upgrade to Firefox 7 that caused this, but I keep getting these annoying ellipsis in the Table of Contents pane:

[image: Screenshot]

This is in OSX Lion, Firefox 7.0.1.

The text appears normal in Safari.

Does anyone know a way to get around this problem in Firefox? Is there some magic setting in about:config that I can tweak?

Does Chrome have this problem?

---

With the help of Boris' answer, this is what I did as a workaround:

1. Created the subdirectory chrome in ~/Library/Application Support/Firefox/Profiles/XXX.default
2. Created a plain-text file named userContent.css in ~/Library/Application Support/Firefox/Profiles/XXX.default/chrome
3. Added the following to userContent.css:

   ```
   @-moz-document   url-prefix(http://developer.apple.com/)
   {
       * { text-overflow: clip !important; }
   }

   @-moz-document  url-prefix(https://developer.apple.com/)
   {
       * { text-overflow: clip !important; }
   }
   ```
4. Quit and restarted Firefox.

Comment: Feel free to bump this question to poweruser (or wherever) if it is not appropriate here.

Comment: I am a huge fan of the documentation that xcode has locally.
You can access it through the organizer --> Documentation.

Comment: When I click on a search result in Organizer's library (say, NSObject), it doesn't show the Table of Contents for NSObject. I then have to manually scroll up and down to find the method that interests me. I also can't cmd-tab quickly from XCode to the Organizer and back. I therefore find the web browser version of the documentation more convenient.

Comment: This might be better as a bug report on Apple's online documentation, because it would seem to be an issue with their website: https://bugreport.apple.com

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firefox 7 added an implementation of `text-overflow: ellipsis`.  Unfortunately, it implemented what the spec said at that point, which does not match what some other browsers implement.  Turns out that what the spec said was completely incompatible with reality.

Since then, the spec has changed in some ways; I suggest trying a Firefox Nightly build to see whether the spec changes address this issue.  I would bet they do, given that screenshot; one of the changes is that the single-value form now only sets the end behavior, not both sides.

As far as your particular situation in Firefox 7, adding

```
* { text-overflow: clip !important; }
```

to your `userContent.css` file for now should help.  If you want to limit it to the one site in question, an `@-moz-document` rule should let you do that.